# Passing String variable to tcpClient.Connect

Tags: c#

I am trying to add the ability to telnet to a user defined IP and port into a program I am working on currently. I got the basic code snippet from a prior question on the site. The issue I am having is that I am unable to pass a text field into the arguments for the tcpClient.Connect method. If I hard code the IP address in the parameters field the code works but if I try to pass a string variable then the tcpClient.Connect does not work and it shows the  catch (exception) MessageBox stating that the connect attempt failed.

I looked at the MSDN for the tcpClient.Connect method and it states it needs (string IPaddress,Int32) as the arguments so I am not seeing why passing the string from a text box is failing.

Here is the code snippet for that section of the program:

```
             int i = Convert.ToInt32(Port.Text);
             String strIP = IP.Text;
            using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    tcpClient.Connect(strIP, i);
                    MessageBox.Show("port Open", "Port Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Port Closed", "Port Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Port closed");
                }
            }
```

Comment: _"it inevitably fails"_ is not in any way a useful problem statement. Please fix your post so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem (hint: if passing a string value to a method is the problem and the string comes back from the UI just fine, then a good [mcve] won't need the UI, just the string), and a detailed explanation of what that code does, including the _exact text_ of any error message and the full stack trace of any exception, and of what you want the code to do instead.

Comment: What is `IP.Text` and are you sure that has a value before you send it as argument to connect method?

Comment: You may be reading from the wrong textbox.  Write the IP using Console.Writeline to very the contents.

Comment: Yes, I have watched it in the debugger and the sting passed is correct for example it will pass 192.168.56.1 which is the IP of the machine that I have a port open on. I have verified that the port is open using the telnet command line in a DOS window. If I change the code to String strIP="192.168.56.1" it will still not connect and will go to the catch (Exception) messagebox showing failure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that when I created the IP textbox in the visual designer at some point a blank space got introduced in the text field property setting. I put some message boxes to see what value was passed to the Method and after running in debugger mode and after testing a few times with different values I was finally able to see the blank space at the beginning of the string variable when it was passed to the method. I went to the text box properties page and backspaced in the properties box to make sure there was no blank spaces. After I did this I was able to successfully pass the IP.text value to the strIP variable and get the tcpClient.Connect method to connect to the IP and port that I passed it.